# JavaScript - How to fix Handlebars Security Vulnerability - from a Dependency's Dependency

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

**Question:** How can I fix a GitHub Security Vulnerability that results from a Library Dependency's Dependencies?

**Context:**

I received the following security vulnerability recently:

1 handlebars vulnerability found in `package-lock.json` 10 days ago

[image]

Adding one of these lines to the `package.json` file does not appear to resolve the security issue.  Rather, the only instance I have found of handlebars being potentially < 4.3.0 is a reference in the `package-lock.json`:

```
"istanbul-reports": {
  "version": "2.1.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/istanbul-reports/-/istanbul-reports-2.1.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-FzNahnidyEPBCI0HcufJoSEoKykesRlFcSzQqjH9x0+LC8tnnE/p/90PBLu8iZTxr8yYZNyTtiAujUqyN+CIxw==",
  "dev": true,
  "requires": {
    "handlebars": "^4.1.0"
  }
},
```

When traversing the dependency chain in the package-lock.json file, "istanbul-reports" is pulled when using Jest.  Unfortunately, below appears to be the most recent version.

```
"devDependencies": {
  "jest": "^24.5.0"
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can remediate or fix this? Thank you!

Comment: [`npm audit fix`](https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities)?

Comment: Thanks, thought of that, but unfortunately, I am not able to find the Vulnerability that Github mentioned when running `npm audit`.  I have also upgraded `npm` (--version) to v6.13.4.

Comment: This is an interesting question, I have tried what @DanO mentioned already but unfortunately did not work.

Comment: Yarn's selective dependency resolution should do exactly what you want requires you to switch package managers tho https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/ that's why I post as comment ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

You should be using {{double handlebars}} unless you explicitly want your input not to be escaped (which you want 99% of the time, as user input can never be trusted.)
Here are the docs - https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#html-escaping

if e.g. you let your user input data and then display it on your page in {{{input}}} a user could use that to insert a malicious script